# How can I make my ngx-line-chart responsive?

Tags: angular, charts, responsive, ngx-charts, ngx-admin

I'm using ngx-admin and I'm trying to make my ngx-line-chart responsive.

My chart is in a nb-card, and when I resize the window the nb-card is totaly responsive. So I want my chart to be resized to fit inside the nb-card.

My html code:

```
<div style="margin: 100px auto auto">
    <nb-card>
        <nb-card-header>XXXXXXXXXX</nb-card-header>
            <nb-card-body>
                <ngx-line-chart></ngx-line-chart>
            </nb-card-body>
    </nb-card>
</div>
```

my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-line-chart',
    template: `
    <ngx-charts-line-chart
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="multi"
      [xAxis]="showXAxis"
      [yAxis]="showYAxis"
      [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
      [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
      [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
      [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel">
    </ngx-charts-line-chart>
  `,
})
export class LineChartComponent {
    showXAxis = true;
    showYAxis = true;
    showXAxisLabel = true;
    xAxisLabel = 'Date';
    showYAxisLabel = true;
    yAxisLabel = 'Services effectués';
    colorScheme = {
        domain: ['blue'],
    };
    themeSubscription: any;
    multi = [
        {
            name: 'Services effectués',
            series: [
                {
                    name: '01/01/2019',
                    value: 156,
                },
                {
                    name: '02/01/2019',
                    value: 134,
                },
                {
                    name: '03/01/2019',
                    value: 140,
                },
                {
                    name: '04/01/2019',
                    value: 167,
                },
                {
                    name: '05/01/2019',
                    value: 158,
                },
                {
                    name: '06/01/2019',
                    value: 178,
                },
                {
                    name: '07/01/2019',
                    value: 310,
                },
            ],
        },
    ];

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

I already try to get the screen size to change my chart size with the screen size but it wasn't perfectly responsive.
To change the size of the chart I can use a variable view=[x, y].
I read in the ngx-line-chart documentation that if no size is defined the chart fit to his container, but in my case it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After some research I found the solution to my problem.

1) To change the chart size when the window is resized:

To change the chart's size I used a "onResize(event)" method. This method take in parameter the window resize event. In this method I simply get the width of the window, I divide it by a ratio (in my case it's 1.35) and I assign it to the width of my chart.

onResize(event) method:

```
// view is the variable used to change the chart size (Ex: view = [width, height])

onResize(event) {
    this.view = [event.target.innerWidth / 1.35, 400];
}
```

My html template:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
  (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [results]="multi"
  [xAxis]="showXAxis"
  [yAxis]="showYAxis"
  [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
  [view]="view">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

2) To change the chart size on different device:

To change the chart's size on different device I have to define the size of the chart into the constructor. I get the window size and like for "window resize" i divide it by a ratio and i assign it to "view".

My constructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.view = [innerWidth / 1.3, 400];
}
```

This answer work for me. I hope it will help you.

Comment: how to fix ngx chart bar vertifcal overflow its parent div...

Comment: how to fix ngx chart bar vertifcal overflow its parent div

Answer (score 39):

I came up with a better & simple solution for this :

componenet.html

```
<div #containerRef class="card-body">
  <ngx-charts-line-chart
    [view]="[containerRef.offsetWidth, 400]"
    [scheme]="colorScheme"
    [legend]="legend"
    [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
    [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
    [xAxis]="xAxis"
    [yAxis]="yAxis"
    [timeline]="timeline"
    [results]="_lineChartData"
  >
  </ngx-charts-line-chart>
</div>
```

Makes It responsive as per container's width.

UPDATE

if you want to make it responsive as of container for both height & width :

```
<div #containerRef class="card-body">
 <ngx-charts-line-chart
   [view]="[containerRef.offsetWidth, containerRef.offsetHeight]"
   [scheme]="colorScheme"
   [legend]="legend"
   [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
   [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
   [xAxis]="xAxis"
   [yAxis]="yAxis"
   [timeline]="timeline"
   [results]="_lineChartData"
 >
 </ngx-charts-line-chart>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for height. Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: Use `[view]="[containerRef.offsetWidth, containerRef.offsetHeight]"` , This will work with height & width

Comment: @ParthDeveloper could you please add it as an answer since it works perfectly

Comment: For me, there was a recursion. When we update the size of the child, depending on the component, the parent is readjusted.

Comment: @RafaelPizao Can you please share live link of code or stackblitz link so, we can have a look on it and help you with it.

Answer (score 2):

Neither of the above two answers completely worked for me. But basing myself on the above logic, that's how it worked for me:

**chart-component.html**

```
<div class="card">
  <div #ContainerRef class="card-body">
    <ngx-charts-pie-chart
      (window:resize)="
        resizeChart(ContainerRef.offsetWidth)
      "
      [view]="view"
      [results]="dataDashboard"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      legendPosition=""
      [labels]="showLabels"
      [legendTitle]="''"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
    >
    </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
  </div>
</div>
```

**chart-component.ts**

```
/* ---- Auto resize chart ---- */
private resizeChart(width: any): void {
  this.view = [width, 320]
}
```

Thus, scaling according to the size of the parent div